# MySQL Insert multiple rows while using 'where not exists' and there is no primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I have a table named friends which you can see below. There are two columns userId and friendId, neither of which is a primary key. Each time I make an insert to the table, I add 2 rows. I would like to be able to check if at least one of the rows already exists before inserting, and if it does, prevent both rows from inserting. To help visualize:

```
 +---------+----------+
 | userId  | friendId |
 +---------+----------+
 |   11111 |   22222  |
 |   22222 |   11111  |
 |   11111 |   33333  |
 |   33333 |   11111  |
 +---------+----------+
```

If I try to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO friends (userId, friendId) VALUES (11111, 22222), (22222, 11111)
```

I want the query to not do anything since this would just replicate the first 2 rows of the table.

Any help in writing this query would be appreciated.

Comment: Create `BEFORE INSERT` trigger since `CHECK` constraint is ignored by MySQL.

Comment: Can you run an ALTER_TABLE statement to make both columns a composite key?

Comment: @ McAdam331, I have complete control over the db so I can run ALTER_TABLE. I was not aware composite key is a thing. I'll look into it.

Comment: After some brief research, it seems that composite keys require primary keys? Did I misunderstand? My table can't have primary keys.

Comment: why on earth would you not have a composite Primary key? There is no excuse for ever having a table without a PK. This is a data integrity mess waiting to happen.

Comment: why you have to always insert two rows at a time? why one is not enoug? a composite key will surely help, but it won't completely solve the problem since I think that (1,2) is considered equivalent to (2,1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trigger to abort the insert of a duplicated record:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tablename_abort_insert`
BEFORE INSERT ON `tablename`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE message VARCHAR(255);
  IF (EXISTS(
        SELECT *
          FROM tablename
          WHERE
            (userId, friendId) IN ((new.userId, new.friendId),
                                   (new.friendId, new.userId))
     )) THEN
    SET message = "Duplicated record";
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = message;
  END IF;
END//
```

Answer (score 1):

This query solves your problem, but it has to be called for each pair of values.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE friendsTemp
(`userId` int, `friendId` int);

INSERT INTO friendsTemp
    (`userId`, `friendId`)
VALUES
    (22222, 11111),
    (11111, 22222);

INSERT INTO friends(userId, friendId)
    SELECT * FROM friendsTemp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM friends
                             WHERE (userId = 11111 AND friendId = 22222) OR 
                               (userId = 22222 AND friendId = 11111));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO friends (userId, friendId) VALUES (11111, 22222), (22222, 11111)
```